# What are some problems (namespace..permissions..etc.) that you see with this particular way of resolving Python's import problem?

Tags: python, import, namespaces

I wrote this little function that i have been using basically everywhere in my current python project and am wondering what are the pitfalls that i don't see. My project is in part a bunch of scripts calling each other from nested directories and that's how i'd like to keep it for now.

This function is meant to resolve the issue whereby *"the following is a major limitation of Python imports: When running a script directly, it is impossible to import anything from its parent directory.* (quoting this [piece](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html))

```py
def root_self(rootname:str='')->None:
    if rootname = '':
       return
    import os,sys
    """Appends the rootpath for the project to syspath.
    An assumptions is that it's unique in the current directory tree."""
    ROOT = os.path.abspath(__file__)[:os.path.abspath(__file__).find(rootname)+len(rootname)]
    sys.path.append(ROOT)
    load_dotenv(os.path.join(ROOT,'.env')) #this can stay or go depending on what env-reader i'm using
root_self('ribxz')
```

I stick it at the top of `__main__` and can import things into scripts with any 3.8 namespacing now from directories below, above and it's quite convenient. Why not?

Comment: @RandomDavis Considering the lack of context, it's not really a Code Review question.

Comment: @RandomDavis It's close there, still open here.